# Run Process keyword doesn't run the .exe file on Team city

Tags: robotframework, teamcity

My robot framework test contains part, where I run .exe file. I am using Run process keyword from Process library.

```
${result}    Run Process    path_to_the_file/file.exe    cwd=path_to_the_file/
```

When I run this locally, the file is executed and response is like this:

```
14:35:34.553    INFO    Waiting for process to complete.    
14:35:34.634    INFO    Process completed.  
14:35:34.634    TRACE   Return: <robot.libraries.Process.ExecutionResult object at 0x055963D0>  
14:35:34.634    INFO    ${result} = <result object with rc 0>
```

When I run this test on Team City, the file is not executed ( properly )

```
5:27:27.587     INFO    Waiting for process to complete.    
15:27:27.786    INFO    Process completed.  
15:27:27.786    TRACE   Return: <robot.libraries.Process.ExecutionResult object at 0x012C1310>  
15:27:27.786    INFO    ${result} = <result object with rc 3221225781>
```

Edit: I tried google for that return code from Team city run and I found something like this:

> 3221225781 = [$id=DLL_NOT_FOUND, $desc={Unable To Locate Component}
> This application has failed to start because %hs was not found.
> Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.]

Does anyone have this sort of experience and what can I do with it?

EDIT2: after deeper analysis I found out, that there are missing DLLs on the agent. So once I'll add missing DLLs I'll know if that was a source of this isue

Comment: As you already noticed, Error code 3221225781  indicates that the app you try to run fails to start because it is trying to open a DLL which does not exists or is not in PATH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution for this issue was to add missing DLLs. Once I added the newest version of Microsoft Visual C++ package, the Run Process executed the .exe file properly.